# What is the easiest way to duplicate an OO / LO macro dialog?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

In OpenOffice / LibreOffice Calc, what is the easiest way to duplicate a macro dialog?

I've got one built already for a particular task, but I need another that is only slightly different, and don't want to have to build it from scratch. I tried editing the ODS as a ZIP, and duplicating the dialog resource, but when I re-opened the file, I got a warning that it was corrupt, and the duplicate was automatically removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have an .ods file with an embedded dialog called `Dialog1`. Unzip the .ods file and make the following changes:

- Copy and paste `Dialog1.xml` to `Dialog2.xml`
- Edit `Dialog2.xml` and change the ID to `dlg:id="Dialog2"`
- Edit `dialog-lb.xml` and add `<library:element library:name="Dialog2"/>`
- Edit `META-INF/manifest.xml` and add `<manifest:file-entry manifest:full-path="Dialogs/Standard/Dialog2.xml" manifest:media-type="text/xml"/>`

Now zip the file back up, making sure to zip it where `META-INF` is the folder at the first level. There should be no more warnings about a corrupt file.

If the dialogs have been localized for more than one language, then all string IDs have to be unique. For example `&amp;241.DlgSpellSearch.Title` would need to be changed to `&amp;242.DlgSpellReplace.Title` and the corresponding entries in `DialogStrings_es_ES.properties` (Spanish-Spain locale as an example) need to match.